# How to debug _Layout.cshtml in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working MVC application

> How do I debug _Layout.cshtml in chrome as I am not able to see it in Chrome Developer Toll("F12")?

I want to check whether @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) is getting called or not Or throwing any error.

The code is working fine in local PC but not on the server and it is a Windows Authentication.

Comment: check server configuration or try to print the value of User.Identity.IsAuthenticated so can have idea what is the value returned by server.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you able to add breakpoint right in Visual Studio at this line, and see what is the value there.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed put some @if statements in your layout page to show the configuration.. Had some troubles myself setting up the AD authentication, so wish you goodluck :).